# Bind a value from a polymer element to the parent page

Tags: binding, polymer-1.0

I have made a simple ploymer element, i need to change an input value on the page that contains that polymer element.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="dial-buttons/dial-buttons.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="dial-number" id="num-input" />
    <paper-material elevation="1">
      <dial-buttons></dial-buttons>
    </paper-material>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the element code:

```
<dom-module id="dial-buttons">

    <template>
        <div on-click="handleClick" data-args="0, num-input">
            <p>0</p>
            <span>+</span>
            <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'dial-buttons',
            handleClick: function(e) {
                var args = Polymer.dom(e).path[1].getAttribute('data-args').split(',');
                document.getElementById(args[1]).value = args[0]; //Here is the issue!
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

What im trying to achieve here is, when a click event on the "dial-buttons" element is fierd, the input value on the parent page should get the value sent from this child element.

Answer (score 0):

Checked that part in the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-notification).

You create a property which is called let's say myVar, you set notify to true (just like the first example). Inside your function set this.myVar to the value you want and it should be reflected to your attribute which you bind to in your parent element.